# How to Load multiple excel sheets data to the same table in SSIS?

Tags: t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am bit confused on my business scenario and need your's valuable suggestion to go ahead .

I got one excel work book template from the client and it is having 8 sheets and 250 columns and each sheet having different columns and there is no relationship from one sheet to other sheet in terms of column names (one sheet has 60 columns with 5000 rows and other sheet has 10 columns with 200 rows ) as well as data also . 
I Need to load this data into single table using SSIS ?

Our client confirmed there will not be change in their inputs ?

Comment: What should the populated table look like?   Will the data from the first sheet be on the same rows as data from the second sheet?   Or each sheet gets its own set of rows?

Comment: Many thanks Tab Alleman , I am not sure who gave -1 as invalid question , I would believe they didn't understood the business scenario . Kindly review my answer  posted my self.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps for ur scenario
1- create a table which has all the columns in excel sheets. If column names are repeating on multiple sheets. You will have one time in your table.

1- bring data flow task. Bring excel source. Make connection to ur excel. Choose sheet1 and then bring oledb destination and map input columns to table. If the column names in table will b same in ur sheet. They will map automatically.

2- bring second data flow. Bring excel souce. Use existing excel source n choose sheet2. Get oledb dest n map to ur destination table.

Get third data flow n load third sheet. Repeat for ur all sheets.